# Using node.js to consume soap

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

Im trying to learn node.js and using node-soap package to consume this simple soap.
WSDL is given here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9o79f8jejqwfp3/UserDataService.wsdl and imported one is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vz0eoh70kvx1bm/import_UserDataService.wsdl

Note the import in the parent WSDL.

So Im executing the following to consume the soap operation removeUser but im getting an error "Invalid child type". Does that mean imports cant be done ?

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://localhost/idmsrvc/UserDataService?wsdl';
var args = {id: 'bladigblahddfdfdfdfdfd'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  client.removeUser(args, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

***node test.js***

```
assert.js:92
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: Invalid child type
    at DefinitionsElement.addChild (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:383:5)
    at Element.endElement (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:143:14)
    at Object.p.onclosetag (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1162:9)
    at emit (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:615:33)
    at emitNode (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:620:3)
    at closeTag (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:861:5)
    at Object.write (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1294:29)
    at WSDL._parse (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1165:5)
    at WSDL._fromXML (/home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1171:27)
    at /home/kasunt/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:676:14
```